# Ubuntu 21.04 nothing happens when message: "Press Ctrl-C to cancel all filesystems checks"

Tags: boot, fsck, 21.04

Ubuntu 21.04,  my computer also get message: "Press Ctrl-C to cancel all filesystems checks", and does not go on...

Any final solution?

Temporary solution is:

If your computer also get message: "Press Ctrl-C to cancel all filesystems checks", and does not go on...

> then press Ctrl+Alt+Del; and when message appear again, press quickly Ctrl+C, and after login, go to "Terminal":

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

> replace "quiet splash" with "fsck.mode=skip quiet splash"

> if using nano only: Ctrl+X / key Y / Enter

sudo update-grub

> Reboot computer.

After future new Ubuntu updates, try removing it again, to see if problem was solved.

Comment: Correct: You must hit CTRL+C *immediately* when the check starts if you want to cancel it. Keep in mind that we get a LOT of questions that turn out to be a corrupt or mis-made installer -- the Ubuntu developers added that check in response to feedback from support volunteers. We generally want everybody to run the check at least once when they create a new install media. That's why it's opt-out instead of opt-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was errors in EFI (FAT-12/16/32) without repair...

Solution:

backup /etc/fstab e /etc/mtab

using Disks go to "Edit
Partition" change EFI to W95 FAT32 (LBA), mount and copy folder EFI to safe place

using Disks format EFI with FAT, copy folder EFI back to EFI partition

change FAT back to EFI (Edit
Partition)

do not forget to also restore UUID of EFI partition

in terminal:

mkdosfs -i 12345678 /dev/sda?

change 12345678 with original UUID in /etc/fstab or copy the number from Disks...

restore /etc/fstab e /etc/mtab

remove fsck.mode=skip from /etc/default/grub

sudo update-grub

reboot...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am happy that you found the answer to your question. Please don't put [SOLVED] in your answer. Your answer is the solution. To mark your answer as the correct solution, accept your answer as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark ✔ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.