# 21.04 okay if boot from bios?

Tags: uefi, do-release-upgrade, 21.04

On my System76 ratel pro (bought in 2015) the command:
`dmesg | grep "EFI v"`
produces no output (whereas on my galago pro laptop the same query gives me v2.60). I read that this means the ratel boots from BIOS rather than UEFI.
Does this imply that the shim bug that is discouraging upgrades from 20.10 to 21.04 does not apply here and I can go ahead and upgrade?

Comment: If your computer does not use UEFI, and only boots using the old BIOS, the shim bug should not matter for this computer. However, I always wait 2 or 3 months after a new release to get all the bugs ironed out, before I upgrade.

Comment: pls read my early post maybe helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334200/ubuntu-21-04-nothing-happens-when-message-press-ctrl-c-to-cancel-all-filesyste/1334712#1334712